Trouble understanding Haskell type unification with a nested `fmap`
I came across this problem while looking at free monads, but have brought it down to a much smaller example.
In Haskell we have the following type:
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

Suppose also we have the following function:
foo :: Num a => p -> a
foo = \_ -> 1

Then
fmap foo :: (Functor f, Num b) => f a -> f b
-- and
fmap (fmap foo)
  :: (Functor f1, Functor f2, Num b) => f1 (f2 a) -> f1 (f2 b)

Then one would expect we can apply fmap (fmap foo) only to something of type (Functor f1, Functor f2) => f1 (f2 a), but
fmap (fmap foo) foo :: (Functor f, Num b, Num (f a)) => p -> f b

What? Why does this type check, and why does it have the given type?
If someone were able to explain what's going on here, that would be very much appreciated. I'm sorry for the vague title, but I don't understand enough what's happening here to make it more specific. I'm happy to update it to something more searchable after a response clears it up.

I mean, if you want, you could define your own Functor, and define a Num instance for Functor Foo with Foo being of your choice. There's one thing that goes ok with that signature.

On an unrelated but important note, the correct way to think about the type of the first argument to fmap (fmap foo) is not forall f1 f2. (Functor f1, Functor f2) => f1 (f2 a), but rather exists f1 f2. (Functor f1, Functor f2) /\ f1 (f2 a), using notation from the first-class existentials GHC proposal. Here /\ is to => what exists is to forall and what (,) is to (->): a left adjoint. This is something even advanced Haskellers get wrong.

foo is a function, so using fmap on it (as the second argument) selects the Functor instance for functions, where fmap = (.). So you are asking why fmap foo . foo has the given type, which is a straightforward unification problem:
foo      :: Num x              => p ->   x
fmap foo :: (Functor f, Num b) =>      f a -> f b

Thus we have x = f a and the resulting type signature is (Num (f a), Functor f, Num b) => p -> f b.

Thanks, this answers the question. For some reason I was thinking that both fmaps in the expression have to be instantiated with the same concrete type, which is obviously not true. I could rename the question to "why am I an idiot"!

@Piturnah I reject the idea that this makes you an idiot. It's sort of inevitable that where there's confusion, there's a reasoning error somewhere. I think you did a good job of explaining your reasoning, which made it easy for answerers to pinpoint the exact spot where the mistake lay, and that's a good thing, not a weakness!
